# how to get data from array in json file to table using react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, json-server

I need to link shipment numbers to the driver and display the data in the table

[image]

- Note that I am using json server

[image]

Table

[image]

Comment: Please, put a parts if your code instead of screenshots so we can help you, and specifying what result you exactly expect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JSON.parse` the ShippmentNumber. Then map over the array of numbers and wrap them with `<a>` tags.

Just an example we can replace the line `<td>{shippment.ShippmentNumber}</td>` with

```
<td>
  {JSON.parse(shippment.ShippmentNumber).map(number => {
    return <a key={number} href={`<shipment-path>/${number}`}>{number}</a>
  })}
</td>
```

Comment: Can you write a simple example